# fully faithful Fourier-Mukai for stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, stacks

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9809114 Theorem 1.1 gives a fiberwise criterion for a Fourier Mukai functor to be fully faithful.

I am looking for a similar result on stacks with the maps being not necessarily schematic.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0210439.pdf

Comment: "schematic"="representable by schemes" (as opposed to "by algebraic spaces")?

Comment: @AliCaglayan: Yes I saw that article, but it only deals with the converse. i.e. the author assumes the functor is fully faithful.

Comment: @Qfwfq: yes, because in the schematic case you can reduce to the previous result. I imagine with some more work you can reduce also from more general situations but I was wondering if someone had not already done this.